# cin keyword not working in text editor

Tags: c++, cin

I'm using the scite text editor (I cannot make use of any IDE or compiler since I'm required to also utilize Makefiles which is only possible if I use some sort of text editor) for all of my coding in c++. However, I'm consistently facing the same challenge; the text editor (I've attempted this on multiple ones including codepad and sublime text) isn't reading any input from the keyboard. Here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 5;

int main(){
int x, y;
int counter = 0;
int elements[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
cout << "Please enter a number ";
cin >> x;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Please enter a choice ";
cin >> y;
if(y == 1){
 for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
  elements[i] = -1*SIZE_OF_ARRAY + x;

 for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; j++)
  cout << elements[j] << " ";
}

 else if(y == 2){
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
   if(i == 0)
    elements[i] = -1*x;
   else{
    elements[i] = elements[i-1] + 1;
   }
}

for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; j++)
 cout << elements[j] << " ";
}

else if(y == 3){
 for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
  counter++;
  elements[i] = 7*x*counter;
 }

for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; j++)
 cout << elements[j] << " ";
}
}
```

The program is supposed to take as an input any number from the user and, depending on a numeric choice (between one and three) entered by the user, manipulate the value first entered somehow.

Choice one (User picks first choice)
The program negates the size of the array and adds the number which the user first entered and fills the array with the resulting value.

Choice Two (User picks second choice)
The program negates the number entered by the user, places this in the first array location then each successive element is added one unit more than the previous one.

Choice Three (User picks third choice)
Fills the array with the first five multiples of seven. Then shifts each number by a factor equivalent to the number the user had first entered.

I've ran it on an IDE (Codeblocks) and it works perfectly well. However, on any text editor, the 'cout' statements are printed with the variables x and y taken to each be equal to zero rather than being set to the value entered from the keyboard. It doesn't even allow any keyboard input. Any answer regarding how I can fix this would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: This is most likely not a problem of the editor you use, but how you build and run it. And we don't know how you build and run it.

Comment: `cin` is not a keyword. It is the name of a class instance.

Comment: Please indent the code to make the readable

Comment: What operating system are you attempting to compile on and what compiler are you using? (if you are using codeblocks, you are probably on windows and probably have mingw installed -- which is fine). Let us know. It is obvious you are confusing what codeblocks can do automatically with what you should be doing from the mingw command line (or from the VS command line -- if you are using `cl.exe` as your compiler) Your code runs fine, though you need a final `cout << '\n';` before exiting so you don't mess my prompt by failing to output the final newline.

Comment: And use braces - they help

Comment: @EdHeal I'll get working on that. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @David I'm on windows and use the gcc compiler (with mingw). In any case, I'm not quite sure what you mean when you reference that I should be doing something from the command line that isn't done automatically since the program does compile and run. Or maybe there's something additional that I have to do in which case, I'd really appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: If you installed Msys, then just open the Msys window which is a command prompt setup with mingw in the path. If you just installed mingw, the `start menu-> (rt-click on My Computer)-> Properties-> Advanced System Settings-> (advanced tab)-> Environment Variables` and add the path to mingw in the **Top** user variables box. Usually adding `c:\MinGW\bin;c:\MinGW\mingw32\bin` is all that is needed (check your install path). Now simply open a `command prompt` and compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o yourexe yoursource.cpp`. Always learn from the command line `:)`

Comment: As your coding grows and you need to add library paths (e.g. paths to where you stored the gtk window builds, etc..), simply add their paths to your user variables box in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoosain, continuing from the comments above, when you use an IDE, you must configure the path to your compiler as well as all compiler options you wish to use, and the location for the resulting executable and object files, etc. When you used CodeBlocks on windows, you essentially got lucky that CodeBlocks will automatically detect whether MinGW is installed and set its compiler configuration to allow you to build and run your code without you having to configure the compiler details. [Geany](https://www.geany.org/download/releases) is another editor that does a good job auto-detecting and using MinGW.

For the remaining IDE's it is up to you to configure them to find and use the compiler you have installed (MinGW), as well as configuring all desired compiler options (at minimum enable compiler warning with `-Wall -Wextra`).

That is where new programmers who have only used an IDE configured for them run into problems... Before you can tell an IDE where your compiler is located and which compiler options you want to use, you have to know where you compiler is located and understand what minimum set of compiler options you should use.

The way you learn to use a compiler is with the good old command line. (yep, that's `cmd.exe` on windows, often labeled as the "DOS Prompt" in earlier versions) An IDE is just a front-end to your compiler that executes the same commands you can simply enter on the command line to compile your program.

Learning how to use your compiler will save you an incredible amount of time when learning to code. You can simply open a command prompt and compile any file you wish, without setting up a project, etc.. When learning to code, trying to shoehorn small examples into an IDE is much more time consuming and often more trouble than it is worth. Rather than worry how to use an IDE, focus on "how to use your compiler" first.

Since you have MinGW installed on windows, all you have to do to be able to compile from the command prompt is add the path to the MinGW `bin` directory to your User Environment. You do that by adding the `PATH` as an Environment Variable here:

```
Start Menu-> (rt-click on Computer)-> Properties-> 
Advanced System Settings-> (Advanced tab)-> Environment Variables
```

In the **Top** window (your user variables), click to add (or edit) the `PATH` "Variable name". Generally, if you installed MinGW in the default location, you simply add the path as the "Variable value":

```
c:\MinGW\bin;c:\MinGW\mingw32\bin
```

(verify the path on your computer)

(**note:** windows separates path components by the semi-colon, so if there is already a `PATH` variable set, just add a semi-colon between what is there and what you add. Also if you already have a command prompt open, you must close it and open it again for the new path to take effect) Just open `Start Menu-> Accessories-> Command Prompt` (you can rt-click on the icon (top-left) and choose `Properties` to set the font (recommend Lucida Console 12) and height/width)

Now you have configured your command prompt to allow you to compile any file at any location within your filesystem. For example, I tested with the code you posted (I modified it to add prompts for the information). Compiling it is a piece of cake. I keep my executables in a `bin` directory to keep sources and binaries separate.

I named your file `array_get.cpp`.

**Compile**

Then just enter the normal `g++` compiler command, and at minimum use `-Wall -Wextra` options to enable compiler warnings (you can add `-pedantic` and whatever additional warnings you want, I would recommend at least adding `-Wshadow` so your compiler will warn on any variables you declare in multiple scopes that could conflict). The `-o` option allows you to specify the location of the executable (I just use a separate `bin` directory as explained above). So to compile and link your code into `bin\array_get.exe` all I have to enter is:

```
C:\Users\david\Documents>g++ -Wall -Wextra -o bin\array_get array_get.cpp
```

(do not accept code until it compiles without warning -- read any warning (it gives line of problem), understand what it is telling you, and go fix it)

**Example Use/Output**

```
C:\Users\david\Documents>bin\array_get.exe
Please enter a number: 21
Please enter a choice (1-3): 3
147 294 441 588 735
```

That's it. Since MinGW uses `gcc`, the compiler commands you use on windows are the exact same you would use in Linux, so learning to compile from the command line pays double-benefit.

Now you have the luxury of using any text-editor to edit your code while you have the command prompt simply and easily re-compile as you wish until your code is correct. No project dialogs, no mess of a different folder for every file, just the freedom to compile any file you wish -- right from the command line. (I actually separate my sources in directory by type, e.g. c, cpp), you find what works best for your. I also use a simple `bat` file that takes the exename and source.cpp names as arguments and then compiles with the options I set -- it just cuts down on typing `:)`

Further, since you now where your compiler is located, and which options to use, you can open the Settings window on any IDE and set the appropriate compiler command and compiler options to allow the IDE compile your code for you.  Give it a try, and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I added the path `c:\MinGW\mingw32\bin` as you have noted and using a modified version of your `g++` compilation command, it worked (can't thank you enough). The tip for creating a hierarchical folder structure for separating the executables and source files is really helpful too. I merely have one more speculation (if you could maybe clear it out); by including a makefile in the bin folder, do you think a `make` command on the cmd (from anywhere) would be recognized, since consistently re-compiling after every edit using the same command can get somewhat tedious?

Comment: Sure (except the Makefile goes with your sources, not your executables), MinGW, includes `mingw32-make` which will read a `Makefile`. Now I have found some differences between what a Makefile on windows and a Makefile in Linux will accept internally, but for a simple Makefile you should be fine. There are a few differences between Win7 and Win10 as well. (also note, you and use PowerShell as your command prompt too).

Comment: Also, don't forget, all you have to do is press the `Up Arrow` key (or on Win10, the down-arrow) to load the last executed command in the command line (that eliminates all retyping `:)`

Comment: By naming the mingw32-make to just make, everything works like a charm; plus your tip on eliminating the extra typing in the cmd is now a bonus (since I've got a working makefile). You've made my day!

Comment: There is always more than one way to "skin-a-cat" `:)`. Glad I could help. Seriously, if you learn to compile from the command line, you will never have any more problems fighting with an IDE. Over 30 years of coding, I've tried IDE's, and always found them to be more trouble than they are worth. Nothing wrong with using them on huge projects where they are meant to help, but they can be a royal pain, and an impediment to learning for small projects. Good luck with your coding! And, If my answer helped, don't forget to choose it as answering your question.